# Python patching order is unexpected

Tags: python, python-unittest, patch

Given the following code:

```py
import os
from unittest.mock import patch
 
def sys_exit_new1():
    print("sys_exit_new1:", os.environ.get("BANANA"))
def sys_exit_new2():
    print("sys_exit_new2:", os.environ.get("BANANA"))
 
@patch("sys.exit", new_callable=sys_exit_new1)
@patch.dict(os.environ, {"BANANA": "1"})
@patch.dict(os.environ, {"BANANA": "2"})
@patch("sys.exit", new_callable=sys_exit_new2)
@patch.dict(os.environ, {"BANANA": "3"})
def test_mytest(m1, m2):
    ...
 
test_mytest()
```

The test will produce:

```
sys_exit_new2: 2
sys_exit_new1: 2
```

Can someone please explain why? The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#nesting-patch-decorators) says:

> Note that the decorators are applied from the bottom upwards. This is the standard way that Python applies decorators. The order of the created mocks passed into your test function matches this order.

If this was true, I would expect it to output:

```
sys_exit_new2: 3
sys_exit_new2: 1
```

So `patch.dict` is behaving differently.

Comment: Show us something that runs and reproduces the posted output when run. What you've posted doesn't do that.

Comment: `NameError: name 'patch' is not defined`

Comment: @Mike: That edit doesn't reproduce the posted output. It just introduces broken syntax.

Comment: I didn't edit to make it work, that's @Blazes' job to finish. I just added the explicit import for the decorator. Nothing worse than code (even not working code) that doesn't show all its imports.

Comment: @Blazes: This isn't the original version of your post. This is after I edited it to reproduce the error. Your original post raises `NameError: name 'patch' is not defined`: https://ideone.com/vH1bGw

Comment: @user2357112 - noted. sorry about that. tyvm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`unittest.mock.patch` does something kind of weird, that most decorators, including `unittest.mock.patch.dict`, don't do.

The first time you decorate a function with `unittest.mock.patch`, it generates a patcher wrapper, and sets a `patchings` attribute on the wrapper, containing a list of stuff to patch. If you apply `unittest.mock.patch` again, it just [updates the `patchings` list](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.11.5/Lib/unittest/mock.py#L1366-L1368), rather than generating a new wrapper.

So, when you decorate your function, these things happen in order:

1. `@patch.dict(os.environ, {"BANANA": "3"})` generates a wrapper that patches `os.environ['BANANA']` to `"3"` and calls the original function.
2. `@patch("sys.exit", new_callable=sys_exit_new2)` generates a wrapper with a `patchings` attribute. This wrapper applies whatever patches the `patchings` list says to apply, then calls the BANANA-3 wrapper.
3. `@patch.dict(os.environ, {"BANANA": "2"})` generates a wrapper that patches `os.environ['BANANA']` to `"2"` and calls the `patch` wrapper.
4. `@patch.dict(os.environ, {"BANANA": "1"})` generates a wrapper that patches `os.environ['BANANA']` to `"1"` and calls the BANANA-2 wrapper.
5. `@patch("sys.exit", new_callable=sys_exit_new1)` detects that the BANANA-1 wrapper already has a `patchings` list (inherited from the BANANA-2 wrapper, which inherited it from the original `patch` wrapper). Instead of generating a new wrapper, it updates the `patchings` list and returns the BANANA-1 wrapper.

So at the end, `test_mytest` is set to the BANANA-1 wrapper, which calls the BANANA-2 wrapper, which calls the `patch` wrapper, which calls the BANANA-3 wrapper, which calls the original function.

When you call `test_mytest`, you're calling the BANANA-1 wrapper. That calls the BANANA-2 wrapper, which calls the `patch` wrapper. At the point the `patch` wrapper is called, `os.environ['BANANA']` is set to `"2"`. At this point, the `patch` wrapper applies both patches the `patchings` list says to apply, so it calls your `sys_exit_new1` and `sys_exit_new2` functions. Since `os.environ['BANANA']` is set to `"2"` at this point, that's what both your functions print.

Comment: thank you for your awesome response. I was digging around the `patchings`, so y, agree it's different and weird. Your response makes a lot of sense but from a practical, maintainable standpoint, engineers would need a PhD in `patch` and decorators. I'm kind of put off the idea of using decorators maybe go with the context manager instead.